# How can I observe when UIPopoverController is dismissed?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

`UISplitViewController` has the delegate method:

```c
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
```

I'm looking to obtain functionality from a similar, but non-existent, delegate method:

```c
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willDismissViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
```

Thoughts on the best way to do this considering `UISplitViewController`/`UIPopoverController`/`UIKit` in general aren't KVO compliant, so I can't add an observer to `UIPopoverController`'s `isPopoverVisible` property.

Thanks

### Answer:

```c
//Sent when switching to portrait
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc
{  
    ...

    self.popoverController = pc;
    [self.popoverController setDelegate:self];
}

-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
{
    NSLog(@"SHOWING POPOVER");
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    NSLog(@"HIDING POPOVER");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, add the `UIPopoverController` delegate in addition to the `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`:

```c
//Sent when switching to portrait
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc
{  
    ...

    self.popoverController = pc;
    [self.popoverController setDelegate:self];
}

-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
{
    NSLog(@"SHOWING POPOVER");
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    NSLog(@"HIDING POPOVER");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you get that first delegate notification, you're passed a reference to the UIPopoverController that will present the hidden view controller. Register as its delegate, then use the [`-popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPopoverControllerDelegate/popoverControllerDidDismissPopover%3a) delegate method from the UIPopoverControllerDelegate protocol.

Comment: My pleasure :) If you'd like to, you can post your own code solution (in your question right now) as an answer to your own question, then accept it - people skimming the page might be more likely to see it in the "Answers" section, especially with the green "accepted" checkmark.